# SOAPUI How to increase value by 1 in Property Transfer target?

Tags: soapui

Having two test steps and trying to get Property Value from one test step into another and increase it by 1. Transfer is not problem but how to increase it by 1?

Comment: Stick a groovey step in between your two test steps.  In the grocery step, pull in the value of interest from step 1.  Put in a return statement where value = value +1.  Finally, in the second step, pull the now incremented value from the groovey step.

Comment: @ChrisAdams +1. After reading the headline, that is what I too would suggest. Depending on the specific testcase, you may even drop the Property Transfer, and then use the Groovy Step result directly.

Comment: Hello Steen, yes, really good point.  There's is absolutely no need for Prop Transfers with my suggested solution.  Just noticed some typos in my text, so I'll fix those.

Comment: I've tried as follows...

Answer (score 0):

I've tried as follows... 
Created a property at test case level "incrementValue" and assigned value 1. 
Added Request "GetNextCrossMessage 1 - Request 2" and in this request added ${#Property Transfer#incrementValue} to the input element in the request. 
Added Groovy Script:

```
def incrementValue = context.expand( '${#Property Transfer#IncrementValue}' );
incrementValue = incrementValue.toInteger() + 1;

if (incrementValue <= 10) {
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("IncrementValue", incrementValue);
log.info "IncrementValue: "+incrementValue;
testRunner.gotoStepByName("GetNextCrossMessage 1 - Request 2"); 
}
```

Getting error in groovy script: java.lang.numberformatexception: For input string "". Where is the problem please?

Comment: Are you using a Property transfer test step?  The flow of your test is really not clear.

Answer (score 0):

If the above code is indeed a Groovy test step, then the issue is line 1.  Your code looks like it wants the IncrementValue value from a Test Step named 'Property Transfer', but your text says you have added a custom property to the Test Case, name IncrementValue.

To 'pull' in a value from the Test Case customer properties, you need to do this...

```
def incrementValue = context.expand( '${#TestCase#IncrementValue}' );
```

or

```
def incrementValue = testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue("IncrementValue");
```

The error you're getting is because you're trying to write an integer to a string property.  Cast the integer to a string and it'll work.

See example...

```
def incrementValue = testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue("IncrementValue");

incrementValue = incrementValue.toInteger() + 1;


if (incrementValue <= 10) {
    // Prop name AND value are strings...
    testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("IncrementValue", incrementValue.toString());
}

log.info(incrementValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everybody especially Chris. I've modified it a bit and this is Groovy Script for increment the value from TestSteps level...

```
def terminalid = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("GetNextCrossMessage 1 - 
Request 1") .getPropertyValue("terminalid");
terminalid = terminalid.toInteger() + 1;

if (terminalid <= 2) {

testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("GetNextCrossMessage 1 - Request 2").setPropertyValue("terminalid",terminalid.toString())
log.info(terminalid);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's almost 1,5 year old and it was resolved with groovy script, but original question was referring to Property Transfer, so maybe some viewers will find solution with mentioned step useful.

1. Add `Property Transfer` step between source and target steps.
2. Add new `Property Transfer` inside.
3. Set **your source step** as **Source**.
4. Set **ResponseAsXml** for **Property**.
5. Set **XPath** for **Path language**.
6. In formula field type something like `${#ResponseAsXml#count(//e/id)}+1` (*you have to replace **`//e/id`** with xpath of property you want to increment*).
7. Set **your target step** as **Target**.
8. Set **desired property** as **Property**

[See example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXHrC.png)

In above example I am:

- getting list of project members in `GetMembers` step,
- counting them by `id` and incrementing in `SaveUsersCnt` step,
- passing the value to `UsersInheritedCnt` variable in `Vars`,
- using it later in assertion of `GetMembersIncludingInherited` step.